# SimpleDateFormat returns invalid date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm facing a really strange problem I haven't seen before. I have a date in milliseconds and want to display it as a readable date. This is my code:

```
if (validUntil == 0) {
  return activity.getResources().getString(R.string.forever);
} else {
  Date startDate = new Date(validFrom);
  Date endDate = new Date(validUntil);
  if (startDate.compareTo(endDate) < 0) {
    String date = sdf.format(startDate) + " - " + sdf.format(endDate);
    return date;
  } else if (startDate.compareTo(endDate) == 0) {
    return activity.getResources().getString(R.string.forever);
  }
}
```

As you can see I just want to create a string which shows the time span. When I debug into my code, the date objects contain the right values while `sdf.format(...)` gives me an invalid date.

Example:

- `startdate` in milliseconds: `1375017555000`
- `startdate` object contains: `Sun Jul 28 15:19:15 CEST 2013`
- `sdf.format(startDate)` returns: `28.19.2013`

I get a simillar result for the end date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the pattern for sdf. probably you put mm instead of MM

Comment: Guess: you're using `m` instead of `M` for months.

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE] (http://sscce.org/)? This will help everyone to better understand you code and answer faster. In this particular case, can you edit your question and show how you have declared `sdf`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably it seems you have used `mm` to denote `months` , but it should be `MM` . Look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

> M  month in year
>
> m  minute in hour

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 5):

You get minutes instead of months. Your pattern should be like this: "dd.MM.yyyy"

Comment: Thank you very much that was the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your date format string is incorrect. This works:

```
public static void dateFormat(){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
    }
```

Result:

2013-07-29